# Steps in a single frame

Tags: beamer

So I'm creating a beamer on overleaf (it's a site that lets you write in LaTeX and compile it automatically and then download a PDF of your work), and I'm wondering how I can make it so that when viewing the beamer I can make different lines on the same frame appear at different times, progressively ? 
Like the first two lines would appear, then the third, then the fourth and fifth and so on. 
The obvious way is to "duplicate " the frames, each frame being copied as many times as needed, but only the first two lines would appear on the first copy and so on. But I was wondering if there could be a more subtle approach, some built in functions etc.

Comment: A primitive method is `\pause`. For more information, please see the beamer user guide, section `9 Creating Overlays`.

Comment: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf